# Ubuntu 20.04 LTSで、tensorflowのディープラーニング学習にGPUが使用できるか確認したい。

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tensorflow, keras, gpu

Ubuntu 20.04 LTSで、GPUを使用してtensorflowの学習を行いたいのですが、使用しているPCのGPUがtensorflowに対応しているかの確認はどのようにすればよろしいのでしょうか。
ターミナルで、

```
$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

とすると、

```
01:00.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: NVIDIA Corporation TU116 [GeForce GTX 1650 SUPER] (rev a1)
```

と返ってくるため、NVIDIAのGPUを使用しているのだと思ったのですが、Pythonのコンソールで

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

と打つと、

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

と返ってきました。

CUDAやCudnnのインストールを行えば、Num GPUs Availableの数字が変わるのでしょうか。
（実際には、CUDAとCudnnのインストールは行ってみたのですが、初心者のため失敗している可能性も高いです。）

このPCのGPUはtensorflowで使用可能か、可能であれば、どのような手順が必要か、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

---

追記

https://qiita.com/porizou1/items/74d8264d6381ee2941bd
https://qiita.com/yukoba/items/c4a45435c6ee5d66706d

上記サイトを参考に、全てターミナルから、
・nvidia-driver-470
・CUDA 10.1(?)
・cuDNN 7.0(?)
をインストールしました。

Comment: ①「CUDAとCudnnのインストールは行ってみたのですが」…どのような手順でしょう？ Ubuntuパッケージから？ PPA？ NVIDIAサイトから？ ⇨質問に追記してみて下さい
② GPUは [CUDAには対応してる模様](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#GPUs_supported) (向いてるかどうかは別にして)
③ 環境変数の確認や動作確認には[Tensorflow with GPU](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/gpu.ipynb)が参考になるかも

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。インストール内容を追記しましたが、CUDA, cuDNN、Tensorflowに多くのバージョンの対応関係に気が回っていませんでした。GPUがCUDAに対応しているとの情報をいただきましたので、再度、1からインストールを行ってみようと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ nvidia-smi
```

のコマンドがエラーだったため、NVIDIAドライバのインストールからやり直しました。

https://k-hyoda.hatenablog.com/entry/2020/07/09/223907
https://contentsviewer.work/Master/Ubuntu/Install/nvidia-tf/nvidia-tf

上記サイトの通り、NVIDIAドライバ、CUDAのアンストールnouveauの無効化、を行った後に、

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive
から、CUDA 11.4.0を、(Linux, x86_64, Ubuntu, 20.04, deb(local)を選択して)インストール。

https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download
から、cuDNN 8.2.4 for CUDA 11.4をインストール。

tensorflowは2.5.0を使用すると、

```
>>>import tensorflow as tf
>>>print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

Num GPUs Available:  1
```

となり、tensorflowの学習時にGPUが使用されるようになりました。